# Prevent jQuery server-side call when client side validation fails in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, client-side-validation

I have a view page with model validations and client side validation enabled. I have a submit button which on click I have called  a javascript function which uses jQuery for an AJAX call to the server..but I want to stop the AJAX action when client side validations fails. Any idea how to?

```
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "hiajax" }))
   {%>
<%= Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
<div class="formRow">
<%if(Model.ListFacility.Count !=0){ %>
    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.ListFacility)%><span class="err">*</span><br />
    <%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ListFacility, (SelectList)ViewData["FacilityBulletin"], new {onChange="updateSiteId()" })%>
   <span class="err"> <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ListFacility) %></span>
    <div class="clear">
</div>
<%} %>
<div class="formRow">
    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.FacilityBulletin) %><span class="err">*</span><br />
    <%= Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.FacilityBulletin,  new { @class = "tinymce" })%>
   <span class="err">   <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FacilityBulletin) %></span>
    <div class="clear" />
</div>
<div class="formRow">

        <%=Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.Active, new { style = "float: left; margin-right: 10px;" })%>
    <span style="float: left; padding-top: 1px;">Active</span>
    <%=Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.SiteId) %>
</div>
<div class="formRow">       
    <input type="image" name="Save" src='<% =Url.Content("~/images/btn_save.png") %>'  onclick="SaveBulletin();" />
</div>
<% } %>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function SaveBulletin() {
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "FacilityBulletin/FacilityBulletin/SaveBulletin",
        data: $("form.hiajax").serialize(),
        success: function (data) { alert(data); }
    });
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having an `onclick` attribute on your your image submit button use the [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) action of the form:

```
$(function() {
    $('form.hiajax').submit(function() {
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        $.ajax({
            type: this.method,
            url: this.action,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) { alert(data); }
        });        
        return false;
    });
});
```

Also notice how the url is no longer hardcoded in javascript but read from the `action` attribute of the form. Of course you need to fix your `Html.BeginForm` as well in order to supply the proper controller and action the form has to be sent to.

Comment: i have removed the onclick event on input type="image" and modified my javascript as per ur code ... but it seems that even though the validation is false the server side event is still being called ?

Comment: Maybe there's some javascript error which prevents the script from running correctly? What does `FireBug` say?

Comment: i have added this in the form tag   using (Html.BeginForm("SaveBulletin", "FacilityBulletin", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "hiajax",area="FacilityBulletin" }))                  and also in the input image i have removed the onclick attribute... and here is teh javascript         $(function () { $('form.hiajax').submit(function () {tinyMCE.triggerSave(); $.ajax({ type: this.method, url: this.action,  data: $(this).serialize(),                 success: function (data) { alert(data); }   });
                return false;
            });
        });

Comment: no error at all.. the server side function gets executed and the alert box is displayed ..i m displaying an alert on success

Comment: i m using MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation

Answer (score 0):

While not specifically geared towards MVC, you can manually call and check client-side validation though javascript, as follows:

```
function SaveBulletin() 
{
    Page_ClientValidate();

    if (Page_IsValid) 
    {
            // do Ajax call
    }
}
```